# Droppoint Support for Mac

Tags: flowgear

Good Day,

Is there a roadmap for the drop points to support MacOS or is there another way to get drop point like access to MacOS?

Currently the Drop point only supports Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

The platform is being moved over to .NET 5 but as of yet, there isn't a way to run a DropPoint on a Mac. One workaround if you want to simulate picking up a file would be to inject it at the start of a Workflow using a Variable Bar property of type File.

Comment: Hello thanks for the response. I am actually looking to drop files to a macbook from one of my completed workflows for the client to view the files as they are mostly running on macbooks.